# How do I configure Dancer2 and Template Toolkit to use a different Stash module

Tags: perl, template-toolkit, dancer

How would I modify the default configuration of Template Toolkit in a Dancer2 site to make use of [Template::Stash::AutoEscaping](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Stash::AutoEscaping)?

Answer (score 6):

You can obviously not write Perl code that creates a new object in your configuration file. Instead, I would subclass the Dancer2::Template::TemplateToolkit class, make the modifications there and then use that instead.

If you look at the code or [D2::T::TT](https://metacpan.org/source/CROMEDOME/Dancer2-0.205001/lib/Dancer2/Template/TemplateToolkit.pm#L16) you can see that it creates and returns the `$tt` object in the method `_build_engine`. If you wrap this in an `around` in your subclass, you can grab it and make the changes.

```
package Dancer2::Template::TemplateToolkit::AutoEscaping;

use Moo;
use Template::Stash::AutoEscaping;

extends 'Dancer2::Template::TemplateToolkit';

around '_build_engine' => sub {
    my $orig = shift;
    my $self = shift;

    my $tt = $self->$orig(@_);

    # replace the stash object
    $tt->service->context->{STASH} = Template::Stash::AutoEscaping->new;

    return $tt;
};

1;
```

This is a bit of an ugly hack and rummaging in the internals of a class is never a good idea, but then [Template::Context](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Context) does not provide a way to change the `stash` object. The `->stash` method is only a reader and it can only be set at runtime.

You can then use your new subclass in your config file instead of `template_toolkit`.

```
engines:
  template:
    TemplateToolkit::AutoEscaping:
      start_tag: '<%'
      end_tag:   '%>'
```

Note that this will make you loose any configuration you might have added for the `STASH` in your config file. You'd have to explicitly grab the config in your wrapper, filter out the `STASH` if there is one and pass it along to the new `new`. I will leave that as an exercise for the reader.